'never tried it' type of answers
In this question about removing scratches on clear part, all the answers are guesses and untried concepts. 
I could start flagging all of them as non-constructive or should somebody clean this up and mention that guesses are not a good answer?

I've protected it and added the standard "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer" message.
There were some potentially useful (if untried) suggestions, which I've moved into the comments.
Cheers.
Edit to add:
That said, a little googling suggests that the last answer should be a good bet: Novus does appear to be a good fit for polycarbonate plastic - which is what the transparent bricks are made from...

There are 'never tried it' answers that still provide some value, based on knowledge about how the problems is typically solved in other arenas.  I took a stab at this question with that in mind and while there could be more a authoritative answer the general problem of plastic removal in scratches does not have only one type of solution.
